# cannot use object as array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, excel, object

I trying to read data from excel by this code

```
$row['name']     =    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $l)->getCalculatedValue();
```

var_dump returns string(4) "CCC3"

but i have a strange problem

code

```
$row['name']     =
```

returns Cannot use object of type PHPExcel_Worksheet_Row as array
If I use simple

```
$row_name =
```

its ok....

to read data Im using phpExcel.

Of course, I can change it to second option, but I dont know, why its not working

thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

I was making the same mistake. I just corrected the mistake by renaming `$row` with some other variable.

Here is what I have done:

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile(ABSPATH.$row['file_path']);
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objReader->setReadFilter( new MyReadFilter() );
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load(ABSPATH.$row['file_path']);

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load(ABSPATH.$row['file_path']);
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $rowsheet) {
    $cellIterator = $rowsheet->getCellIterator();
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); 
    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
        $headarray[]= $cell->getValue();
    }
}
```

Notice i have changed

```
foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
                      $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
}
```

to

```
foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $rowsheet) {
                      $cellIterator = $rowsheet->getCellIterator();
}
```

and it's working like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

`$row` is an object, so you cannot set properties this way unless it implements [`ArrayAccess`](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php). Your question makes me think `$row` is just an unused variable at that point, in which case you can `unset` that and/or make it an array like `$row = array();`.

Answer (score 0):

You've already set the value of `$row` as a PHPExcel_Worksheet_Row object earlier in your script, perhaps using PHPExcel's row iterator, so `$row` already exists as an object. This means that you can't simply rely on PHP to redefine it as an associative array when you assign a value to it as `$row['name']`.

Either use another variable name (e.g. $rowdata) that hasn't previous been used, or `unset($row);` before trying to assign a value to it.